# findOne filtering by objectId always returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Developing node.js app. For some reason this findOne call always returned undefined, even though I have verified that the req.params.id is valid and it should return data...

```
let event = await Event.findOne({ venue: ObjectId(req.params.id) });
```

I've also tried....

```
let event = await Event.findOne({ venue: req.params.id });
```

Here's part of my model definition for Event....

```
const EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  eventDate: {
     type: Date
  },
  venue: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
     ref: 'Venue'
  },
```

In postman I am doing a **DELETE** http verb against **/venues/5e0401c4a246333ca4ced332** url for your information.

Basically I'm wanting to search for the venue id in the events table. I'm seeing if this venue is being used by an event before I decide to delete it.

Here's the entire method...

```
// @desc    Delete venue
// @route   DELETE /api/v1/venues/:id
// @access  Private
exports.deleteVenue = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let venue = await Venue.findById(req.params.id);

  if (!venue) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(`No venue with the id of ${req.params.id}`, 404)
    );
  }

  if (req.user.role !== 'manager' && req.user.role !== 'admin') {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`Not authorized to delete venue`, 401));
  }

  // the following line always returns undefined even though the venue 
  // exists in the events table.... then it jumps to the end of the method
  let event = await Event.findOne({ venue: ObjectId(req.params.id) });

  if (event) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(
        `You cannot delete a venue because events are tied to it.`,
        404
      )
    );
  }

  await Venue.remove();

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: {}
  });
});
```

Using Compass, looking at the events collection I definitely see records using the id I submitted...

```
_id:5e045b6e0c38f2502440ecb7
attendees:Array
eventDate:2020-01-01T05:00:00.000+00:00
venue:5e0401c4a246333ca4ced332
status:"planning"
```

I did...

```
  console.log(`id is ${req.params.id}`);
  let event = await Event.findOne({ venue: req.params.id });
```

The results showed I was passing the correct id.... (console output)

```
id is 5e0401c4a246333ca4ced332
ReferenceError: Event is not defined
    at C:\Projects\abc\controllers\venues.js:90:15
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `req.params.id` that you get.

Comment: Are you sure you have a record with that `venue` ?

Comment: Can you also please post the complete code for the delete function you have at the moment

Comment: @AnkitaKuchhadiya  venue id is 5e0401c4a246333ca4ced332

Comment: `await Event.findById` should be `await Event.findOne()`

Comment: @AnkitaKuchhadiya I'm sorry, a typo. Yes, I was using findOne originally. Still is always undefined. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not importing your Event model.
You need to add:

```
const Event = require("../models/event"); //you need to change the path
```

After that you need to find the event like this:
 `Event.findOne({ venue: req.params.id })`.

Also I have a few suggestions:

1-) It makes more sense to check role authorization in the beginning.

2-) First check if there is any Event for the given Venue, and if there is no events, use `findByIdAndDelete` method. This way we can reduce number of db access, since we eliminated `Venue.findById`

3-) In the case a venue has events, using a 404 status code does not seem correct. 
I think 400 - Bad request is more appropriate.

4-) mongoose converts _id's, so there is no need to use ObjectId.

```js
exports.deleteVenue = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

  if (req.user.role !== "manager" && req.user.role !== "admin") {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`Not authorized to delete venue`, 401));
  }

  let event = await Event.findOne({ venue: req.params.id });

  if (event) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`You cannot delete a venue because events are tied to it.`,400));
  }

  let venue = await Venue.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

  console.log(venue);
  if (!venue) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`No venue with the id of ${req.params.id}`, 404));
  }

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: {}
  });
});
```

Test:

Let's say we have the following two Venue document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0471e3394d1e2b348b94aa"),
    "name" : "Venue 1",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0471eb394d1e2b348b94ab"),
    "name" : "Venue 2",
}
```

And one Event document whose venue is Venue 1 with id 5e0471e3394d1e2b348b94aa:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e04727c76da213f8c9bf76a"),
    "eventDate" : ISODate("2019-12-26T11:41:16.019+03:00"),
    "name" : "Event 1",
    "venue" : ObjectId("5e0471e3394d1e2b348b94aa")
}
```

When we want to delete the Venue 1, this will result with the following error, because it has an event:

`You cannot delete a venue because events are tied to it.` with status code 400.

Comment: Thanks. But event is always undefined event if I try this: let event = await Event.findOne({ venue: req.params.id });

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 I tested this code, and it works. I guess you are not sending a id param correctly. Please check.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 cCan you add a console.log(req.params.id) to the beginning and check if it is correct and and an existing venue id?

Comment: I posted the DELETE path I'm using in postman. And I'm checking the request param in the findOne line. It is correct. :( So weird.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2 check if it is an existing id  in the collection. Also what is the signature of your router?  it must have :id in the route url, like router.delete("/venue/:id")

Comment: I updated the end of my original post. Shows it correct.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2  did you import Event model? like `const Event = require("../models/event");`

Comment: it says here it couldn't find Event in this line :venues.js:90:15

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204892/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-webdevguy2).

Comment: The problem was I did not define Event up above! NEWBIE mistake! So sorry. Thank you so much @SuleymanSah You are the BEST!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Do it with findOneAndDelete of mongoose and Expressjs:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) { //checking if id valid
    return res.send("Please provide valid id");
  }
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);  // passing it into a var
  Event.findOneAndDelete({ venue: id }).then( res.json({ success: true }));
});

module.exports = router;
```

for details https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-findOneAndDelete

Comment: I'm wanting to search for the venue id in the events table. Basically I'm seeing if this venue is being used by an event before I decide to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.deleteVenue = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

  //First check role. Because it not call database
  if (req.user.role !== 'manager' && req.user.role !== 'admin') {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`Not authorized to delete venue`, 401));
  }

  //Next step, check event
  const event = await Event.findById({ venue: ObjectId(req.params.id) });

  if (event) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(
        `You cannot delete a venue because events are tied to it.`,
        404
      )
    );
  }

  //Delete venue by Id
   await Venue.deleteOne({ id: req.params.id }, (error, result) =>{
      if(error) return next(
      new ErrorResponse(`No venue with the id of ${req.params.id}`, 404)
    );

      res.status(200).json({
         success: true,
         data: {}
       });
   })

});
```